# Regular Expression to match pattern A and not pattern B

Tags: .net, regex, redirect

Background:

I have a Url redirecting system that works with regular expressions.

URLs with the format: http://www.company.com/{any number of parent pages}/parentX/{any page}.aspx

need to be redirected to: http://www.company.com/parentY/parentX/{the page}.aspx

In other words, all pages with immediate parent X and any number of grandparent pages, now live under parentY/parentX.

I can easily write a regular expression to match a URL to http://www.company.com/{any number of parent pages}/parentX/{any page}.aspx. However, this would also match the pages I am redirecting to (resulting in a redirect loop). So, my expression needs to not match the pattern http://www.company.com/parentY/parentX/{the page}.aspx

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: negative lookahead right after `http://www.company.com/` ?

Comment: Or match them all and check in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#http://www.thecompany.com/(?!parentY).*/parentX/[^/].aspx#
```

I'm using a negative lookahead assertion.  `(?!...)` is a zero width assertion that ensures the regex inside does not match at this starting position.  Not knowing which language you're writing in, I'm not sure if you can do this, or if it could get fancier (For instance, whatabout  `http://www.thecompany.com/parentY/parentZ/parentX`?) - but this should work for the situation as you've given it here.

Comment: Should have said - this is .NET